# Android screen resolution in web app not constant

Tags: javascript, android, screen-resolution

This is weird. I'm using javascript to figure the resolution in a web page. For that I have a following function (somewhat simplified for this purpose):

```
function check() {
    var win = document.defaultView || document.parentWindow,
        ratio = win.devicePixelRatio ? win.devicePixelRatio : 1,
        h = win.innerHeight,
        w = win.innerWidth,
        root = document.documentElement;

    if (!h) {
        h = root.clientHeight;
        w = root.clientWidth;
    }
    alert("height/width/ratio; " + h + "/" + w + "/" + ratio);
```

}

on android devices there seems to be a really peculiar behaviour:

I'll give a Nexus S as an example but obviously I've verified this on many other Android devices running different versions.

If you arrived to the page containing the script above by clicking on a link in an email app (gmail or outlook), the alert will yield 1130/800/1.5 (height and width are way too high). This is consistent. Now, if you go to the address bar and edit the url (add/remove a parameter or parameter value) and hit "Go", the exact same code will yield 452/320/1.5 (thats more like it, and that's also consistent).

How and why on earth is this happening?

EDIT: worth noting is that so far this only seems to apply to devices with devicePixelRatio > 1, i.e. not older Android phones on v 1.5 / 1.6

Comment: Is there browser zoom affecting it?

Comment: I cannot imagine, no. The page looks the same in both instances and the only thing you have to do is to alter the url and reload, not do anything with zoom. I can't see how the zoom would change all by itself in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and debugging, this almost seems like a bug.

The repro is easy: if the above script is run synchronously in onload event and you click on something that opens a new window, email app or a web page with target=_blank, both screen and window width and height properties will be wrong. Makes no difference if you use jQuery, YUI or plain javascript.

The solution/workaround is to wrap the method called in onload in a setTimeout() with timeout set to 0. That will run the method asynchronously and yield correct result.

```
<body onload="setTimeout(check, 0);">
```

That, my friends, closes this case.